# Label text does not update properly

Tags: c#, winforms

I have the following code to update my UI.

```
private async void startButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    progressBar.Maximum = 100;
    progressBar.Step = 1;
    fileListView.Items.Clear();

    var progress = new Progress<ProgressData>(pdata => {
        currentFileLabel.Text = pdata.CurrentFile;
        totalFilesLabel.Text = pdata.CurrentIndex + "/" + pdata.FileCount;
        progressBar.Value = pdata.Progress;
        fileListView.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new string[] {
            pdata.CurrentIndex.ToString(),
            pdata.OldFileName,
            pdata.NewFileName,
            pdata.FileExtension
        }));
    });

    await Task.Run(() => Rename(progress));
}
```

This code does not update **currentFileLabel** and **totalFileLabel** properly. They are only updated after the **Rename** method completes its work. But **fileListView** and **progressBar** are updated without a proplem.

If I remove

```
fileListView.Items.Add
```

method, now labels are properly updated as well.

How can I update all the UI controls properly?

Comment: thats because of exception, youre trying to update UI from another thread, use `currentFileLabel.invoke/BeginInvoke`

Comment: No Invoke required, Progress takes care of it.  The most common bug is a fire-hose problem, calling Report() entirely too often.  Which makes the UI burn 100% core, unable to keep up.  Paint events no longer occur and the UI becomes unresponsive to clicks.  ProgressBar is a bit different, it was written to deal with this kind of bug and forces a repaint.

Comment: @Sinatr, I don't get an exception. Furthermore, isn't the main goal of IProgress interface to get rid of the need to use Invoke in the first place?

Comment: Post the Rename method with the loop where you report the progress